# Tensor contraction defined only for the same underlying variables?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

I'm self-studying tensor and index notation from McCullagh (1987) and I'm going over the definition of **tensor contraction**. As a concrete example, $\omega^{ij}$ and $\omega_{klm}$ are both tensors ($\omega^{ij}$ is contravariant whereas $\omega_{klm}$ is covariant). Then, with
$$
\gamma_{klm}^{ij}\equiv\omega^{ij}\omega_{klm},\quad\gamma_{kl}^i\equiv\gamma_{klj}^{ij}=\omega^{ij}\omega_{klj}
$$
(summation is implicit).

> Then, $\gamma_{kl}^i$ is a tensor because, under transformation of variables, the transformed value is
>   $$
> \bar{\gamma}_{klm}^{ij}=\gamma_{tuv}^{rs}a_r^ia_s^jb_k^tb_l^ub_m^v\tag{$*$}
> $$
>   and, hence, summation over $m=j$ gives
>   $$
> \gamma_{kl}^i=\gamma_{tu}^ra_r^ib_k^tb_l^u.\tag{$**$}
> $$

(The highlighted text above is essentially verbatim from McCullagh.)

Here, I **think** here is how $a$ and $b$ are defined: $\omega^{ij}=f(x^i,x^j)$ and $\omega_{klm}=g(\zeta^k,\zeta^l,\zeta^m)$ and $y$ is a transformation of $x$, $\xi$ a transformation of $\zeta$. Then, $a_i^r=\partial y^r/\partial x^i$ and $b_r^i=\partial\zeta^i/\partial\xi^r$.

I can verify ($*$) without any issue but I can't verify ($**$) unless $x=\zeta$ and $y=\xi$. So my **question** is: is contraction only defined when $\omega^{ij}$ and $\omega_{klm}$ are both defined on the same underlying variables? If it's allowed that $x\neq \zeta$ and $y\neq\xi$, how does one show ($**$)?

---

**Edit**: strictly speaking, I don't need $x=\zeta$ and $y=\xi$ to show ($**$). What I do need is
$$
\delta_i^j=a_i^rb^j_r\tag{$***$}
$$
where $\delta_i^j$ is the Kronecker delta: $\delta_i^j=1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise. ($***$) is satisfied when $x=\zeta$ and $y=\xi$ but I think it might hold more generally.

Comment: Just a little exposition on tensors: Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional real vector space (to make it easy), where $V^*$ represents its dual.  Let $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ be a basis for $V$ and $\{\theta^1, \dots, \theta^n\}$ be the dual basis in $V^*$.  Then a "tensor" ${\gamma^{ij}}_{kl}$ is really just one component of the tensor $$V^*\times V^*\times V\times V \to \Bbb R \\ (\omega^1, \omega^2, v_1, v_2) \mapsto \gamma(\omega^1, \omega^2, v_1, v_2)$$  In fact ${\gamma^{ij}}_{kl}$ is simply the number $${\gamma^{ij}}_{kl} := \gamma(\theta^i,\theta^j,e_k,e_l)$$

Comment: @Bye_World Hi, I find your example helpful in that it helps me understand better what a tensor is. But it doesn't seem to answer my question. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Notice that tensor components are defined with respect to some bases.  So to answer you question: Yes, for the regular transformation rules to apply you must use the same bases in the definition of each tensor in your contraction.